# Manually terminate recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I have written a recursion (actually I found the recursion online) to get all possible permutations of a set of numbers but in some occasions, due to the large number of possible permutations, I would like to add an If statement to terminate the recursion before it goes through all permutations. I have tried entering a return statement but it doesn't seem to work.

I am a bit of a newbie in coding so apologies if the answer obvious to everyone, I just cannot get it.

```
class EntryPoint
{        
    static void Main()
    {           
        //input an initial sequence of the trains to schedule
        Console.Write("Input train permutation");
        string inputLine = Console.ReadLine();

        GenerateTrainOrder GTO = new GenerateTrainOrder();
        GTO.InputSet = GTO.MakeCharArray(inputLine);
        GTO.CalcPermutation(0);
    }
}


class GenerateTrainOrder
{
    private int elementLevel = -1; // elements examined iterates immediately after the CalcPermutation initiates so we must set it equal -1 to start from 0
    private int[] permutationValue = new int[0];

    public int[,] Paths = new int[ParametersClass.timetableNumber, ParametersClass.trainsToSchedule];

    private char[] inputSet;
    public char[] InputSet
    {
        get { return inputSet; }
        set { inputSet = value; }
    }

    private int permutationCount = 0;
    public int PermutationCount
    {
        get { return permutationCount; }
        set { permutationCount = value; }
    }

    //transform the input from the console to an array for later use
    public char[] MakeCharArray(string InputString)
    {
        char[] charString = InputString.ToCharArray();
        Array.Resize(ref permutationValue, charString.Length);

        return charString;
    }

    public void CalcPermutation(int k)
    {            
            elementLevel++;
            permutationValue.SetValue(elementLevel, k);

            //if we have gone through all the elements which exist in the set, output the results
            if (elementLevel == ParametersClass.trainsToSchedule)
            {
                OutputPermutation(permutationValue); // output TrainOrder by passing the array with the permutation 
            }

            //if there are elements which have not been allocated a place yet
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ParametersClass.trainsToSchedule; i++)
                {
                    //iterate until we come upon a slot in the array which has not been allocated an elements yet
                    if (permutationValue[i] == 0)
                    {

                        CalcPermutation(i); //rerun the code to allocate an element to the empty slot. the location of the empty slot is given as a parameter (this is how k increments)

                    }  
                }
            }

            elementLevel--;
            permutationValue.SetValue(0, k);
    }

    private void OutputPermutation(int[] value)
    {
        int slot = 0;

        foreach (int i in value)
        {
            Paths[permutationCount, slot] = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToString(inputSet.GetValue(i-1)));

            slot++;
        }

        PermutationCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the termination condition and where did you try to put `return`? What do you mean "doesn't seem to work"? `return` will always terminate the function and return;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to stop a recursive calculation. The best method involves a global variable (or a private class variable if you have objects).

This variable says if the recursion should stop or not:

```
bool stopRecursion = false;
```

Now inside your calculation you update this variable after each step:

```
if(_my_condition_is_met) stopRecursion = true;
```

At the start of your recursively called method you check the state of this variable:

```
public void CalcPermutation(int k)
{  
    if(stopRecursion) return;
    ...
```

And you check this variable after each call to `CalcPermutation`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ParametersClass.trainsToSchedule; i++)
{
    //iterate until we come upon a slot in the array which has not been allocated an elements yet
    if (permutationValue[i] == 0)
    {
        CalcPermutation(i);
        if(stopRecursion) return;
        ....
```

With this method you *unwind* even deep call levels as soon as your *stop condition* is met.

Comment: First, no globals or fields are required if the recursive function just returns a result to notify it must be stopped. This is esp. important in multithreaded code. Second, .NET 4.5 has the CancellationToken class to signal any kind of function that it should cancel.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP said "I am a bit of a newbie" so the Cancellation Token is probably a bit too much here. The return value is a very good idea of course.

Comment: He talked about to "stop the recursion" not "exit the method". Words are important

Comment: @Hellraiser How could you "stop the recursion" without returning?

Comment: For-loop is a recursion itself. Break stops that recursion. Return exits the method. So please use terms correctly

Comment: @Hellraiser I don't agree: A for-loop is an _iteration_. A recursive method call is something very different.

Comment: And how do you think a for-loop works internally? :)

Iterations are a repetition of a sequence of instructions
Recursion is a repetition of a sequence of instruction + passing parameters to each successive iteration

Comment: @DrKoch all right. Would you explain the 2 then, please?

Comment: @Hellraiser see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion. This is the critical part: "The function calls itself recursively..."

Comment: @DrKoch I repeat, how do you think for-loop works internally? It's just a FUNCTION with PARAMETERS called RECURSIVELY :)

More over: each call to to a recursive function is an ITERATION.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by implementing something which is quite similar to what @DrKoch suggested

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies everyone. I managed to make it work by doing the following:

Under the CalcPermutation(i) line, I wrote

```
if (permutationCount == ParametersClass.timetableNumber)
{
       return;
}
```

I tried running it a few times with different inputs and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ParametersClass.trainsToSchedule; i++)
            {
                //iterate until we come upon a slot in the array which has not been allocated an elements yet
                if({your condition}){
                  break;
                }
                if (permutationValue[i] == 0)
                {

                    CalcPermutation(i); //rerun the code to allocate an element to the empty slot. the location of the empty slot is given as a parameter (this is how k increments)

                }  
            }
```